# Relationship between the girth of a graph and the number of edges

Tags: graph-theory

I'm wondering if there is a relationship between the girth of a simple undirected graph and its number of edges. In particular, given an $n$-node graph $G$ with girth $g\ge 3$, is there an example where the number of edges of $G$ exceed $n^{1 + 1/\Theta(g)}$?

Comment: A complete graph with $n \geq 2$ vertices has girth 3 and always $\frac{1}{2} n (n-1)$ edges.